# trouble with a for loop inside a while loop

Tags: python, for-loop, math

I'm trying to write some code that will find the roots of a polynomial by cycling through various starting values (x0) and running the Newton-Raphson method for each value of x0.

My code is this:

```
import math
import cmath
a0=input("Enter a value of a0: ")
a1=input("Enter a value of a1: ")
a2=input("Enter a value of a2: ")
a3=input("Enter a value of a3: ")
a4=input("Enter a value of a4: ")
def f(x):
    return float(a0)+float(a1)*x+float(a2)*x**2+float(a3)*x**3+float(a4)*x**4
def f1(x):
    return float(a1)+2*float(a2)*x+3*float(a3)*x**2+4*float(a4)*x**3


d=0.000005
dx=0
x0=-6
while(x<5):
 x0+=1
 print("The value of x0 is: ",x0)
 for i in range(100):
    dx=f(float(x0))/(f1(float(x0)))
    x1 = float(x0) - dx
    if (abs(float(dx))>float(d)):
     print(x1)
     x0=x1
    else:
     break
 print("Number of iterations: ",i)
```

Instead of beginning each iteration with the value of x0 that I want (-5 through 5), the while loop always starts the next loop with x0 equal to the value of the previous root.  This is due to `x0=x1` at the end of the loop.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Show the real code (proper indentation with the usual 4 spaces everywhere would also be helpful). There is a global variable `x` used but not assigned.

Comment: @MichaelButscher sorry I'm new to stackoverflow, what do you mean by the real code? The variable x is just used to define the function, it doesn't need to be defined does it?

Comment: Not the function parameter: the loop variable.  You gave us `x` where you meant `x0`.  Your posted code fails to run at all.

Comment: oh yes I see, in the "while(x<5):" line that should be x0, but that doesn't solve the overall problem sadly

Comment: Why all these float conversions? They should happen once for the inputs, inside the calculations there is no need for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to use x0 for two incompatible purposes at the same time: loop control and the current guess at the root.  Try separating those purposes into different variables.

```
guess0 = -6
while(guess0 < 5):
    guess0 += 1
    x0 = guess0
    print("The value of x0 is: ",x0)
    ...
```

Even better, use a `for` loop; they're designed for exactly this problem:

```
for guess0 in (-5, 6):
    x0 = guess0
    print("The value of x0 is: ",x0)
    ...
```

Comment: ah I had a feeling I was using x0 for too many things, thanks for your answer that was very helpful!

Comment: @BenActon: On this site, show your appreciation by upvoting all the useful answers. You do that by clicking the up-arrow at the top-left of the answer, if you have enough reputation to do so. In addition, accept the best answer (if it actually answers your question) by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than saying thanks in a comment. It also helps others to see that your question was answered.